# A path to Higher Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, higher-category-theory

I'm a undergrad student and I'm stidying most of this things on my own, or with help of some professors that are helping me a bit, just for fun and bulding a solid base for my future PHD, with I'm planig on doing on this area.

I want to study [higher geometry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+geometry), I'm quite familiar with category theory and I'm currently studying differential geometry and differential topology, also I know a bit about algebraic geometry and algebraic topology, not much, but I know schemes, some properties of they and their morphisms, also I will be starting to study cohomology soon.

My question is, after having a solid background on Algebraic Gemetry up to be really familiar with schemes and cohomology, be familiar with basic algebraic topology and having a solid knwoledg in differential geometry and differential topology, what should I study and by with sources like books, lecture notes and things like that?

I know that I will probably need to advence my studies in algebraic geometry up to a good understanding of stacks an all you can do with then and higher category theory, but what else whould I need to study and also, good sources for studying this topics are also welcome too.

I know my question is a little too broad, since higher geometry as a very broad subject and I will probably need to chose a part of it to focus my studies, but what I need is the background to start studying it, so I will be able to find the most interesting part of it for me and then focus on it.

And also a second question, I don't know if this is already entangled with higher geometry, but I couldn't find any source about higher topology, does this subject exist?

PS: Sorry for my english, my mother language is portuguese and I'm still learning english.

Comment: I don't know higher geometry but from the looks of the nLab page, it seems like a pretty big prerequisite will be familiarity with homotopy theory and higher category theory.

Comment: Of course, but these subjects also have a lot of prerequisites for thenselves, I'm looking for these prerequisites and also maybe some other subjects that may be important.

Comment: Maybe continue studying algebraic topology (e.g. via Hatcher) since fluency with homotopy theory and simplicial sets is important to understand higher category theory.

Comment: On the other hand, while I applaud that you are already this advanced as an undergraduate student, I'm not sure if you should already be too focused on this one, sort of quite specific direction, there is still a long road towards these "higher" theories and you may discover that some parts you might not like or other parts of mathematics that you become interested in.

Comment: Do you think that Hatcher alone is enough or shoul I look for a book in homotopy theory and simplicial sets after it?

Comment: Sure theres a lot of things that are calling my interest, trasncendental number theory for exemple is one of the most interesting things I've saw in my life, but I don't think that I shouldn't focus on something, if I decide to change my direction someday, at least I will have a lot of knowledge in other areas that may be useful.

Comment: It all depends how well you feel after reading it and how well you can work with Hatcher, you can probably try to read Lurie's HTT afterwards (but more experienced people may say otherwise). But this is not something for you to worry about now, focus on the present and see how far you got and whether you are comfortable enough with those things by then.

Comment: There are other nice books like e.g. books by May which delve a bit further than Hatcher, I believe. (By the way, if you reply to a comment, you should use @, otherwise the the replier will not get notified that you answered/asked another question.)

Comment: @QiZhu Sorry for not replying correctly before, I didn't knew that.

Comment: @QiZhu I will try Hatcher before anything else, seens like a good book for someone to start, I don't know if it have the more advenced topics, but as you've said, I will not worry with this right now, I'm still starting.

Comment: If by "higher" geometry you mean derived geometry, you should get acquainted with the  cotangent complexes of commutative dg algebras, and try to compute the stalks of the cotangent complex of your favorite singular variety. Also the theory of derived intersections will make a good motivation. Can find useful history here : perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2012/04/dag-ems.pdf. Also a very enlightening reading is "A master course on algebraic stacks" for the stacky direction in "higher", you can find it  here : https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/videos-lecture-notes-etc/

Comment: Thanks deeply, derived geometry is a branch of higher geometry (if I got it right), but it's a very interesting branch.